# Jquery - check to see if selector ends with number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check selector to see if he is ending with number?
JS code:

```
if(!$(this).val())
{
   $('label[for^=image], input[id^=image], input[name=time]').remove();                              
}
```

I tried adding **/d/**, but it does not work (

> $('label[for^=image' + /d/ +'], ....

)

Comment: So actually you want to test whether the value of the `for` attribute ends with a number? The whole string `'label[for^=image], input[id^=image], input[name=time]'` is the selector...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**demo** is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/8g2WL/

Behaviour: for the id's ending up with number in `label` you will see an alert.

Hope this helps, please let me know if I missed anything.

**sample code using regex**

```
$('label').each(function(){

    if ($(this).attr("id").match(/\d+$/) != null)
       alert($(this).attr("id").match(/\d+$/));


    });​
```

**html**

```
<label id="foo">hulk</label><br/>

<label id="foo_23">HUlk with number</label><br/>


<label id="foo1">ironman with number </label><br/>

<label id="foo">hulk</label><br/>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use `.filter()` to match with regex:

```
$('label').filter(function(){
    var forValue = $(this).attr("for") || '';
    return /^image\d+/.test(forValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('label')
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr("for").search(/image\d/)==0;
    })
    .html("Matched!")
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extension [Regex Selector for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/). Preview - http://jsfiddle.net/yDA9n/

```
$('label:regex(id,[0-9]$)').css('color', 'red');​​​​​​
```